# How to call method of class 1 on object of class 2 while being in class 3 & Is it good design?

Tags: java, methods

I have to calculate one formula, with certain input parameters.
I would like to create a code that meets the best-practice design principles. As I am studying, so I want to do good from beginning. 
Basically I need to know x, knowing that it is output of function f: x = f( a_1,a_2,a_3). I am doing it in Eclipse. I have decided to create 3 classes: Main, Calculation, Data. 
Where from main I will call everything.
From Data I will generate different a_1,a_2,a_3 arrays and again pass to Main.
From Calculation I will do calc. and then send back to Main.
Here is the code:

```
public class Main{

public static void main(  String args[]){

        double[] fArray = {160, 150}; 
        double[] aArray = {1, 1};
        double[] vArray =  {0.2, 0.3}; 
        double[][] cArray = {{1, .5},{.5,1}};
        double time = 1;
        for (int i=0,i<3,i++){
            Data myfirstobject = new Data( fArray, aArray,  vArray,  cArray,   time);
            System.out.println("message from main method"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Then class Data:

```
public class Data{

    public Data(double[] fArray, double[] aArray, double[] vArray, double[][] cArray,  double time) {
        System.out.println("This is my first parameterized constructor launched");

        System.out.println("This is my first output from costructor : " + fArray[0] + aArray[0] + vArray[0] + cArray[0][1] + time );
        }
}
```

Finally, calculations:

```
public class Calc{

    public static double v_calc(double[] fArray,double[] aArray,double[] vArray,double[][] cArray,double time){
        double numerator = 0;
        double denumerator = 0;
        for (int k=0; k<fArray.length;k++){
            for (int j=0; j<fArray.length; j++) {
                numerator = numerator + fArray[k]*fArray[j]*Math.exp(cArray[k][j]*vArray[k]*vArray[j]*time);
                denumerator = denumerator + fArray[j]*fArray[k];
                }
        }
        return Math.pow(1/time * Math.log( numerator / denumerator), .5);
    }           
}
```

My questions:
1) Is it correctly designed? Especially, if I want somehow( do not know yet how) to call the method of Calc on Data object in the main method.

2) Why I face difficulties if I write in the constructor not:

```
Main myfirstobject = new Data( fArray, aArray,  vArray,  cArray,   time);
```

but this:

```
Main myfirstobject = new Data( {160, 150},{1, 1},{0.2, 0.3},{{1, .5},{.5,1}},1);
```

In this case I get error.

PS. If you find really bad design mistake, please tell.

Comment: You can write `new double[] {160, 150}` instead of `fArray` in the constructor. The only place you don't need to write `new double[]` is when you're initializing the array at the time of declaration like you have done yourself with `double[] fArray = {160, 150};`.

Comment: With regards to `Main myfirstobject = new Data(...`: first, since you're learning, let's get you started with the correct terminology: that code is not in a constructor, but rather in a static method.  Second, that code should give a compile-time error, I think, as `Data` appears not to be a sub-class of `Main`; you probably want to write `Data myfirstobject = new Data(...`

Comment: now it is correct. Sorry, I was making smaller names for StackOverflow, and forgot to change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should create Data objects in Main class instead of Main objects

```
//dont do this Main myfirstobject = new Data( fArray, aArray,  vArray,  cArray,   time);
//insted do this
Data myfirstobject = new Data( fArray, aArray,  vArray,  cArray,   time);
```

you need 'Data' objects, not objects of class 'Main'

Data class should contain private variables to store the data and the constructor should be used to initialize the variables e.g.

```
public class Data {
private double[]fArray,aArray,vArray;
private double time;
private double[][]cArray;
public Data(double[] fArray, double[] aArray, double[] vArray, double[][] cArray,  double time) {
    System.out.println("This is my first parameterized constructor launched");
    // use this function System.arraycopy(source-array, source-index, dest-array, dest-index, lengthto-copy);
    //or simply copy 
    this.fArray=new double[fArray.length];
    for(int i=0;i<fArray.length;i++)
        this.fArray[i]=fArray[i];
    //and soon for other arrays
    System.out.println("This is my first output from costructor : " + fArray[0] + aArray[0] + vArray[0] + cArray[0][1] + time );
}


//getter method to get fArray when needed for calculation in Calc class
public double[] getFArray(){
    return fArray;
}
```

}

like getFArray() you can write other methods to get other variables

in Calc class you should change the prototype of the function v_calc to

```
public static double v_calc(Data myfirstobject){
        double[] fArray = myfirstobject.getFArray();
        double[] aArray=myfirstobject.getAArray();
        //calculate using fArray,aArray soon }
```

and then user getter methods(getFArray,getaArray etc which you will implement) to get values of the data you want to use for calculations and calculate

to call the method you can do this:

```
double ans=Calc.v_calc(myfirstobject);
```

your prototype of v_calc is not wrong but in Object oriented design, it is good practice to pass object around when whole object is needed. as in this case you need whole myfirstobject

its is not easy to understand at first.

for 2nd part of question you can pass refrences to the functions and not raw arrays made inside the functions or you have to get space for the arrays which is not good design and should be avoided. if you dont know about refrences just assume it to be as it is. you will understand it later